# embedded Iframe height not working?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to embed a login page (of an external website) within my website.

I put in the following code

```
<iframe src="https://ticketing.oz.veezi.com/LoyaltyLogin/?siteToken=48tz57nzw85qh7t3yzgzd6s9xc"
width="450" height=“650” frameborder=“0”
```

The issue I'm having is although I've specified the width of 450 which works fine the height at 650 doesn't appear to be working.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osxoP.png)

Here's the link to the page with the code down the bottom - http://avocabeachpicturetheatre.com.au/rewards

Thanks!

Comment: You have fancy quotes in your code, `height=“650” frameborder=“0”` should be `height="650" frameborder="0"`

Answer (score 0):

Wrong quotation marks used. Change `height=“650”` to `height="650"`.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the quotes around `650` and `0` replace with proper quotes `""`
- Add pixel to height and width: `height="650px"`